# Index always refreshing

Tags: php, html

I'm making a dynamic site, and I'm making a reset password through email, and I have this flag in my database so when the user resets his password the value is true, and the next time that user logs in, he will be redirected to the change password page.

I'm working with a single index page with a switch.

```
<?php
session_start();
$lig=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or 
        die ("Problema na ligação ao servidor MYSQL");
mysql_select_db("demo",$lig);
if (isset($_REQUEST['cmd'])) $cmd=$_REQUEST['cmd']; else $cmd='home';
?>

<div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">

                        <?php

            switch($cmd) {
                case 'home': require('home.php');break;
                case 'pw': require('users/pw.php');break;
             }
             ?> </div> </div>
```

I made this code so when reset is different than NULL he redirects the user to the pw.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   if(is_null($_SESSION['reset'])){ 
   }
    else{ echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=index.php?cmd=pw>";
        }       
}
```

but the page seems to be in an infinite loop of refreshing.
I placed this in the index.php page, but if 
I put it in the home page for example it works just fine, I wanted to be able to make this in the index, so I don't have to put it in every single page of my website...
Making the time for the `content=0;` bigger is not a reliable option..
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to destroy the session after the user changes the password, so you only need to check if $_SESSION is setted. This routine I put to orient you towards users that is already logged into page.

```
function changePass(){
//YOUR ROUTINE
   if ($queryExecuted == true){
     session_destroy();
   }
}

//checking session
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
  echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=index.php?cmd=pw>";     
}
```

Your meta is always running because is in else statement, taking ALL OTHER CONDITIONS while $_SESSION['reset'] is not null. Other important thing it's avoid use echo metas, use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) instead:

```
header("Refresh:0");
//or refresh and redirect
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

After user login, don't redirect to index page and to all those validation, just validate inside the own user login routine and redirect to users/pw.php

If you don't want to change all your routine checking, the page always refreshing because is not checking where the user is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !is_null($_SESSION['reset']) && (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] != 'pw')){ 
header("Refresh:0; url=index.php?cmd=pw"); 
}
```

Comment: I set the $_SESSION['reset']  to null, after he does, but thats not the issue, thanks for the suggestion anyways, the issue is, when the user is in the change password page , the page wont stop refreshing making it impossible to change...

Comment: so I changed it to this `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !is_null($_SESSION['reset'])){
 header("Refresh:0; url=index.php?cmd=pw");
 }` but still refreshing

Comment: After user login, don't redirect to index page and to all those validation, just validate inside the own user login routine and redirect to users/pw.php instead to redirect to index.php to check something in the session and send tho change password. My routine to destroy session is about when user go to change password screen, because you'll need to certificate that he will log again.

Comment: well I also thought that but my login is with ajax, and I don't redirect the user to index, the user is always in the index.

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !is_null($_SESSION['reset']) && isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] != 'pw'){ header("Refresh:0; url=index.php?cmd=pw"); }

Comment: Thanks its exactly what I needed, all doe I have another error when I do it, if I change the password I change it, and it refreshes me again to the same change password page, like nothing happened, but if I change it again, it works properly, probably because it already recognized the `reset=NULL` , but the first time I change it and it "doesn't do nothing" it changes the pw

Comment: That why I don't recommend use $_SESSION parameters to validate those routines. When your user changes the password, destroy your session and redirect (with header one more time) to login routine.